# Am I missing something that changed the controls for the first Risen on Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, risen

I recently purchased Risen with the Black Friday sales, I had never played the series but I've been at least vaguely interested in it for a while.  I've played a bit of the game and started enjoying it, but decided to look for the manual so I can further understand the controls.  Long story short, my controls are definitely *not* what the manual says they should be, and as far as I can tell there is no way to change the control scheme in-game.

I got the manual through the Xbox marketplace site, and [this](http://download.xbox.com/content/4b4d07d8/Risen%20Xbox360%20Manual%20UK%20Revised.pdf) is the one I'm looking at.  Here is a small list of the different commands I've noticed

- Jumping is done by pressing (Y), however the book says to click the right stick.
- Drawing my melee weapon is (X) though the book states to press [LB].  Also (X) is supposed to be dodge, but I've yet to find a button that preforms any sort of dodge function.
- Attacking is done with the [RT] and blocking is [LT] though the book states attacking to be (A).
- Using the quick bars is done by holding [LB] and pressing the corresponding quick bar button, though the book states it to be by pressing [LT].

I am playing on the Xbox 360, I've tried with both a wired and a wireless controller, and I am playing in the US (I'm not sure if that matters, since the manual is apparently the "UK Revised" version)

Has anyone played this game recently?  Does anyone know what's causing this or if there was a patch or if the controls varied between UK and US (if so, is there a list of the controls that would correspond to my system?)